# Ubuntu stopped starting in Oracle VM Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox

I have Oracle VM Virtual Box 6.1 and Installed Ubuntu 20.4 inside the VM. It was working perfectly fine.

Just now I installed Docker and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in my Windows to install redis.

After that the Ubuntu stopped launching in VM. (I guess) It is throwing some error(it is so quick, I can't see), then just black screen. I uninstalled Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Still same issue. I followed the below link to install redis/Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

https://redislabs.com/blog/redis-on-windows-10/

Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
I really need Ubuntu in the VM.

Comment: Allow me to confirm the issue: Things were working fine with Ubuntu 20.04 in a VM on a Windows host, then you created a new VM, and now the Windows host is unable to launch any Ubuntu-based VM? This sounds more like a Windows issue than something in Ubuntu, as VMs are completely isolated from each other.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 was working in a VM on a Windows host. I installed  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in Windows (not in VM/Ubuntu). Also installed Docker. Then Ubuntu 20.04 stopped launching in VM

Comment: That still sounds like a Windows problem. VMs are completely isolated from each other. Unless you have decided to share `.vdi` files between VMs and wiped out data in the process, there is no reason for Ubuntu (or any other OS running in a VM) to care about the existence of other virtual machines. Have updates or configuration changes been applied to the 20.04 VM recently?

Comment: No, I haven't updated anything in 20.04 VM. I was working in Ubuntu (inside V) just few minutes back